# I have done *ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I have done *ngFor loop and added click event but I need the click event to the 0-index item. As such it is applied to all the item in the loop

Comment: Please add your full question here.

Comment: Need to see the code

Comment: @Timothy 
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  products = products;
  clickMessage="";
  isHidden:boolean=true
  constructor() {
     }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.products = products.map(product => ({ ...product, isHidden: true }));
  }
  listView(product: any): void {
    this.clickMessage = "You are my Avenger";
    product.isHidden = !product.isHidden
  }
}

Comment: @NithinBabuParavath Please edit the question and put the code there, and make sure to format it so it's easy to read. We also need your html code since that's what seems relevant to this question.

Comment: I think the code snippet that is shown here is what you're looking for https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `products` is an array of objects, you could introduce an additional property to each object to control it's display state.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  products = products;
  clickMessage="";

  constructor() {
    console.log(this. Constructor + "you have entered");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.products = products.map(product => ({ ...product, isHidden: true });
  }

  listView(product: any): void {
    this.clickMessage = "You are my Avenger";
    product.isHidden = !product.isHidden
  }
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<div *ngFor="let product of products | slice:0:3 let i=index">
  <h3>
    <a 
      (click)="listView(product)"
      [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor:'#1e88e5'}" 
      id="list" 
      [title]="products.name + 'details'"
    >
      {{i}} {{products.name}}
    </a>
    <h4 *ngIf="i<1" [hidden]="product.isHidden">{{clickMessage}}</h4>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer
Actually i am getting the below error.

error TS2339: Property 'isHidden' does not exist on type '{ id: number; name: string; price: number; description: string; }[]'.

14       <h4 *ngIf="i<1" [hidden]="products.isHidden">{{clickMessage}}</h4>
                                            ~~~~~~~~

Comment: @NithinBabuParavath: The property is included in `ngOnInit()`: `products.map(product => ({ ...product, isHidden: true });`